# Build is success but publish fails - This version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.All is only compatible with the netcoreapp2.2 target framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, msbuild, publishing

I have a Web API project of below properties

- .Net Core 2.2
- Visual Studio 2017
- version :15.7.4

Project `.csproj` has clearly has below settings

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

Build is `success` in Visual Studio, But when I try to `publish` the project I get below error

> This version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.All is only compatible with the netcoreapp2.2 target framework. Please target netcoreapp2.2 or choose a version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.All compatible with netcoreapp2.1.

I am publishing using `Visual Studio` menu options.
I am publishing to `Azure app service` . Publishing to `File System` is not showing any error.

I have nuget as follow

[image]

What can be the cause?

Comment: How are you publishing the app? Is it a Self-Contained Deployment?

Comment: It's not self contained. I am publishing from visual studio menu options to Azure app service. updated the points in question.

Comment: Sounds like you need to upgrade your version of the framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found a strange solution!

I have created new `publish` profile and it worked like charm! seems like after changing project property from .Net Core 2.1 to .Net Core 2.2 we need to create a new profile always!

Comment: For me it was literally just press the "Configure button" it seems to cause it to update to use `newcoreapp2.2`, save and try again - worked fine

Answer (score 4):

Don't know if it's relevant to you but I found this in the folder publish target location settings:

[image]

Comment: I have the same setting

Comment: Glad you found it :)

Comment: Same issue here. The UI was showing 2.2 but the underlying file still had 2.1. I resaved the file and it worked.

Comment: save my time :)

Answer (score -1):

If I remove the reference to EF.Tools, then publish will NOT Fail.